# Creating a graph based off two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns that I need to combine into a selection in order to graph.  The ending of the data would not also be the same. Can I dumb the selection into a variable?

```
Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Select
Range("f1", Range("f1").End(xlDown)).Select

' create graph
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(?)
End Sub
```

What I'm finding is that column f1 is only getting added to the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row & ",F1:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row).Select
```

Comment: sorry I thought I had.